# Probability for a key to be in a safe

Tags: probability

> Suppose the existence of $N$ safes.
>
> There's a probability $p$ that a key is inside one of the safes (there's either one key in a given safe or no key overall)
>
> Each safe may or may not have the key, **with the same probability**.
>
> Supposing that safes $1,\ldots,N-1$ have been opened and don't contain a key, what's the probability that the last safe has a key ?

Let $A$ be the event "One of the safes has a key inside".

Let $A_i$ be the event "the $i$-th safe has a key inside".

The exercise asks for $P(A_N|\bar{A_1}\cap\ldots\cap \bar{A}_{N-1})$.

We have $P(A)=p$.

Since the $A_i$ are mutually exclusive, since $A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_N=A$ and "Each safe may or may not have the key, **with the same probability**", $$\forall i, P(A_i)=\frac{p}{N}$$

Moreover, $P(\bar{A_1}\cap\ldots\cap \bar{A}_{N-1})=1-P(A_1\cup\ldots\cup A_{N-1})=1-\frac{N-1}{N}p$.

**Question**

It remains to compute $P(A_N \cap \bar{A_1}\cap\ldots\cap \bar{A}_{N-1})$.

How should I do that ?

Comment: The wording is a little confusing! when you wrote "a safe may or may not contain a key with the same probability" don't you mean the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ for having the key then?

Comment: And there's only one key that might be in one of the safes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your 'Question':

I think $A_N\subseteq (\bar{A}_1\cap\bar{A}_2\cap\cdots\cap\bar{A}_{N-1})$.

So $\Pr(A_N\cap(\bar{A}_1\cap\cdots\cap\bar{A}_{N-1}))=\Pr(A_N)$

Comment: That's not true! there may not be any key in all the safes.

Comment: If the key is in safe $N$ then it is not in any of the lower numbered safes, and so I think the subset relation in my post holds.

Comment: right! I misread your argument.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to formalise the problem. Let $X$ a $\{0,1\}$-valued aleator variable, such that $P(X=1)=p$, $P(X=0)=1-p$. Let $Y$ uniform distributed over $\{1,2,\ldots N\}$. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ indipendent. Now we have $A=\{X=1\}$, and $A_i=\{X=1,Y=i\}$. Then $$A_N\cap \bar{A_1}\ldots\cap\bar{A}_{N-1}=\{X=1,Y=N\}$$ $$\bar{A_1}\ldots\cap\bar{A}_{N-1}=\{X=0\}\cup \{X=1,Y=N\}$$
We conclude that
$$P(A_N|\bar{A_1}\ldots\cap\bar{A}_{N-1})=\frac{P(A_N\cap \bar{A_1}\ldots\cap\bar{A}_{N-1})}{P(\bar{A_1}\ldots\cap\bar{A}_{N-1})}=\frac{p/N}{1-p+p/N}$$